# i18n in Java - translation keys to enums / unused keys

Tags: java, eclipse, properties, internationalization, translation

**Problem:**
I have properties files with translations and very simple API that allows me to call for label via the key (standard). I use eclipse IDE for java.

1. I'd like to be able to find keys that are not any more used (some tool support)
2. I'd like to ensure that every key that is used in code has its equivalent in property file.

   Ad.2. I am going to change all key to enums, so that the compiler tells me if any translation is missing.
   In the code there is something like:

   ```
   translations.getTranslation("key")
   ```

   and I want to have :

   ```
   translations.getTranslation(TranslationEnum.KEY)
   ```

Maybe you know any APIs/tools that could help me? Any other ideas how to do it

Comment: What API are you using to read the properties file?

Comment: At the end there is ResourceBundle from java.util.... standard.

Comment: I fear, no. GWT (Google Webtool Kit) has an interesting I18N mechanism. But you can use it only in a GWT project. [link](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18n#DevGuideStaticStringInternationalization)

Comment: See [gettext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext#Operation) library. It's not primarily for Java, but it's widely used and has many tools which can give you interesting hints. It extracts keys from source codes by searching for particular patterns and then uses various tools to check/process them. See also [gettext-commons](http://code.google.com/p/gettext-commons/).

Comment: That is the idea I am going to use: http://code.google.com/p/gettext-commons/  What I need is a tool-parser that will be able to find all key in code base, change all of them to enums and generate enum classes.

Comment: You can try c10n (https://github.com/rodionmoiseev/c10n/wiki/Overview) as an alternative approach to keys. Since in c10n keys are methods, you can't misspell your key, or miss a key. Unused keys can be found using some tool to find all unused methods (IntelliJ inspector has one).

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDE shows unused keys in property files and links usage of keys in source code to property files. So you can see if a key is existing or not.

It's a very cool IDE but is not for free.

So in my project i decided to use [gettext](http://code.google.com/p/gettext-commons/wiki/Tutorial) for translation work and i am happy with it.

1. All sources are parsed and translation candidates are extracted.
2. No unmeaning keys in source but meaningful base text which will displayed if a translation is missing.
3. Maven and Ant supported.
4. Translation comments in source code and translation files for helping the translators.
5. Existing translation tools like [poEdit](http://www.poedit.net/)
6. Out of the box powerful plural handling

Comment: Thanks for your hint, I am actually looking for something for eclipse

Comment: You can use gettext with eclipse! It es a free lib. Its only parsing the code and extract the translation.